# Why is this MySQL query with the NOT IN statement so slow?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a database with a fair number of records in it, and I want to find the users that have no user items stored:

```
select `name`
  from `users`
 where `ID` not in (select distinct `userID` from `userItem`)
```

This query won't even finish executing before it gets cut off by the MySQL server. Is there some huge inefficiency here that I don't know of?

There are 200,000 records in `userItem` and 14,000 records in `users`.

Result from an explain on the query:

```
1   PRIMARY users   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    13369   Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  userItem    index   NULL    userID  8   NULL    189861  Using where; Using index; Using temporary
```

Comment: structure?INDEX? MySQL version?, Engine? can you make a `explain select name from users where ID not in (select distinct userID from userItem)`

Comment: How are name, ID  and userID indexed in their respective tables?

Comment: @jcho360: MySQL client version: 5.1.65. I'm not sure on the engine. Result from explain edited into original post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Are userItem.userID and user.ID indexed? If no, add them.
2. In MySQL JOIN clause may be faster.

For example -

```
SELECT name
  FROM users u
  LEFT JOIN userItem ui
    ON ui.userID = u.ID
  WHERE ui.userID IS NULL
```

Comment: Wow, I feel silly. I thought I had indexed userID, but apparently I had created some weird index that was indexed with another column in the table too. It runs fast now. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @RandyOlson . . . it is a shame that you chose this answer because it will multiply the rows in cases where user id is repeated in userItem.  That means it is not equivalent to the `NOT IN` version of the query.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff That is example. And it is not a problem to add `GROUP BY u.ID` clause to get the same result.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I chose this answer because of the first suggestion, which made me re-examine the indexes in my table, and ultimately solved my problem. I know, my problem was caused by a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is "why" it is so slow.  The reason is because MySQL re-executes the subquery for every row.  You would think it would execute the subquery once, and then be finished.  But no, it will re-execute it a zillion times.

I believe the fastest alternative is a slight variagion on @Parado:

```
select `name`
  from `users` u
 where not exists (select 1 from userItem ui where ui.userID = u.id limit 1)
```

You should use this in conjunction with an index on ui.UserId.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `not exists` will be faster:

```
select `name`
  from `users` u
 where not exists
 (select 1 
  from `userItem` ui 
  where ui.userID=u.id)
```

Comment: You should fix your condition to be ui.userID = u.id.

Answer (score 0):

Create Unique Index on Users(ID) and User-item for (userid).

```
Ex . SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c FROM t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM t2 WHERE t1.a = t2.a AND t1.b = t2.b AND t1.c = t2.c)
```

Using NOT IN is not the best method to do this, even if you check only one key. The reason is that if you use NOT EXISTS the DBMS will only have to check indices if indices exist for the needed columns, where as for NOT IN it will have to read the actual data and create a full result set that subsequently needs to be checked.

Using a LEFT JOIN and then checking for NULL is also a bad idea, it will be painfully slow when the tables are big since the query needs to make the whole join, reading both tables fully and subsequently throw away a lot of it. Also, if the columns allow for NULL values checking for NULL will report false positives.